# verification on two Strings

Tags: java, string, verification

i need help on a verification on a string 
I have to write a method that verify if 2 parameters of the method have the same length and if the second one have numbers between 0 and 3.

Let's see what i wrote :

```
public static boolean coupEstValide( String combinaison, String coup ){
    boolean res = true;
    if(combinaison.length() == coup.length()){
        int i = 0;
        while(i < coup.length() && res == true){
            char t = coup.charAt(i);
            if(t <= 0 && t >= 3)
                res = false;
            i++;
        } 
    }
    return res;
```

in my opinion, this should work... But if i do this :

```
coupEstValide("555", "104");
```

it should tell me `false` but it it's telling me it's `true`.

Do you guys see what's wrong ? 
Thanks

Comment: The character `'3'` is not equal to the integer `3`.

Comment: `if(t <= 0 && t >= 3)` should be `if(t <= '0' && t >= '3')`, assuming "between 0 and 3" means "either 1 or 2".

Comment: Unfortunately, i tried this but it keep telling me it's true... I don't understand : s

Comment: Your verification rule isn't clear to me. Your example "555" and "104", are the same length. "104" has 1 in it which is between 0 and 3, so it should be true. Do you mean 'only have numbers between 0 and 3'?

Comment: @biiwop: But, "104" does not have "the numbers between 0 and 3". Do you mean any one of the digits between 0 and 3, not, as your code currently is, all between 0 and 3?

Comment: yes i did a mistake... it should be : 
`if(t < '0' && t > '3')`

Yes all the number of "coups" have to be between 0 and 3

Comment: @biiwop Of course it returns true, how can `t` be both less than '0' and greater than '3' at the same time? Your condition will always be false.

Comment: if that char length that u need to spify then u need to give some if loop logic.

Comment: one possibilities is to parse that char into the integer and try to compare.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare Character with an integer actually ASCII value of that character gets compared with that integer. That's why you keep getting true.

So as already suggested in the comments you should compare it either as if(t >= '0' && t <= '3') or use any Utility method of java.lang such as Character.compare(char lhs, char rhs).

Hope this would be helpful.

Enjoy!

Comment: Yes, all the number have to be between 0 and 3. if one is not between 0 and 3, it has to be false.
so i change for `if(t < '0' && t > '3')`. But true is still there : (

Comment: It is impossible for `(t < '0' && t > '3')` to ever be *true*. `t` cannot both be less than '0' and greater than '3' at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

A few of problems in your code:

1. If the lengths are different, you are still returning true!
2. Strings are composed of characters. Their value is their character code. `0` to `3` are [48 to 51](http://www.asciitable.com/), respectively. Use character constants not integer constants: `if (t == '0')` will check if `t` is the *character* "0".
3. Your logic for the comparison isn't right anyways. Using your original (incorrect) example with integers, and correcting from `<=` and `>=` based on your comments: `if (t < 0 && t > 3)` will *never* be true, `t` cannot simultaneously be less than 0 and greater than 3. I'll leave the correct boolean statement as an exercise to the reader (hint: **or**).

Answer (score 0):

This would never true. A number can not be less and equal to zero and at the same time greater and equal to 3.

```
if(t <= 0 && t >= 3)
```

If you want to evaluate whether a character is between 0 and 3 you must use this:

```
if(t >= '0' && t <= '3')
```

Now if you want to evaluate if the character is not between 0 and 3 then try this:

```
if (t <'0' || t> '3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i fixed the problem.
So as you said, i should've use

`if(t < '0' || t > '3')`

And to fix the problem of the time both are not the same size, i added an else.

So the full code is that :

```
public static boolean coupEstValide( String combinaison, String coup ){
    boolean res = true;
    if(combinaison.length() == coup.length()){
        int i = 0;
        while(i < coup.length() && res == true){
            char t = coup.charAt(i);
            if(t < '0' || t > '3')
                res = false;
            i++;
        } 
    }
    else
    res = false;
    return res;
}
```

Thanks for your help guys !

Comment: || that will allow if any single condition is true.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Giving a list of sample inputs that should and shouldn't be work (and which should return true/false) would have gotten you answer pretty quick. It is also something you be doing to test this.

Comment: You could also just replace the entire function with `return conbinaison.length() == coup.length() && coup.matches("[0-3]+");`...

Answer (score 0):

```
String coup = "053";
        boolean res = true;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < coup.length() && res == true) {
            System.out.println(coup.length());
            int t = Integer.parseInt(coup.charAt(i) + "");
            System.out.println("T is " + t);
            if (t <= 0 || t >= 3) {
                res = false;
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println("Value i "  + i);
            System.out.println("Value of the Res at last" + res);

        }
```

may be this could be helpful try to convert it to the integer

according to your code

```
String coup = "053";
        boolean res = true;
        int i = 1;
        while (i < coup.length() && res == true) {
            System.out.println(coup.length());
            //int t = Integer.parseInt(coup.charAt(i) + "");
            char t = coup.charAt(i);
            System.out.println("T is " + t);
            if (t <= 0 || t >= 3) {
                res = false;
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println("Value i "  + i);
            System.out.println("Value of the Res at last" + res);

        }
```